# Rails API Versioning Spree + rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've an e-commerce app which built using Spree, now i need to create a new version of the API for a certain controller and here's what i did

- created a new controller in /api/v2/x_controller.rb
- made an action index
- add route for my controller in routes.rb
- made a rabl file ( index.v2.rabl )

when i try to access the api my request hit the action but i keep getting error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template spree/api/v2/x/index)
```

i there any missing configuration i should do ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RABL view should be under

```
app/views/api/v2/x/index.rabl
```

> There is a naming convention for views in Rails. Typically, the views share their name with the associated controller action. For example, the index controller action of the articles_controller.rb will use the index.html.erb view file in the app/views/articles directory. The complete HTML returned to the client is composed of a combination of this ERB file, a layout template that wraps it, and all the partials that the view may reference.

Comment: does it have `index.v2.rabl` as name?

Comment: could you rename it to `index.rabl`?

Comment: yes, it works Thanks, but i need to know why it didn't work with index.v2.rabl  ??

Comment: Because that's how rails works. Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e#views). And if you don't mind, if this answers your question could you accept it?

Comment: sorry didn't get that !, why index.v1.rabl works for version 1 & index.v2.rabl don't work for version 2 ?!